# Avoid useless casts in JGraphT

Tags: java, casting, jgrapht

I'm developing a "table RPG", and i'm using external library JGraphT in order to represent the Map as as UndirectedGraph.

My map is made of 15 cities, each of them has an assigned bonus (configuration file). Every player can build on a city and get that bonus each time he builds. If the player builds in n connected cities, he gets the bonus for each city.

I wrote a method (in class City.java) which, given the map and the player, returns all the cities connected to "this". How can I avoid the "irregular" casts in `Subgraph` and `ConnectivityInspector`? 
Thank you in advance.

```
public Set<City> linkedCities(Map map, Player player) {
    Set<City> linkedCities = null;
    Subgraph sg = new Subgraph((UndirectedGraph<City, DefaultEdge>) map, player.getBuiltCities()); 
    ConnectivityInspector<City, DefaultEdge> inspector = new ConnectivityInspector<City, DefaultEdge>((UndirectedGraph<City, DefaultEdge>) sg);
    linkedCities = inspector.connectedSetOf(this); 
    return linkedCities; 
}
```

Comment: Your `map` variable is  expected to be an instance of `UndirectedGraph`, obviously. Why can't you just pass the map as `UndirectedGraph` as a method parameter? Why do you pass in a `Map`?

Comment: Can you show your Player class, please?

Comment: @Mifeet would it change something? It still gives me a warning..

Comment: @cricket_007 it's too long for a single comment, although it's not relevant for this method..

Comment: Never use comments for code. Always [edit] your question to include additional information